# My balance is always 0 but in my my remix is 1000000000000000 (solidity)

Tags: node.js, solidity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29V0O.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lb2q6.png)

from the picture above it shows that in solidty my balance is 1000000000000000 but in my website it shows 0
I have test it with gananche provider and it works but when i changed to metamask it shows 0.

solidity code:

```
function getBalance() public view returns (uint) {
    return balances[msg.sender];
}
```

html + js:
`GET YOUR BALANCE

Balance: Not Connected to Contract`

`const getBalanceApple = async () => { const data = await window.contract.methods.getBalance().call(); document.getElementById("balanceArea").innerHTML =` Your balance: ${data}`; }`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your contract is working fine but you're failing to read the contracts balance on your frontend.

For debugging purposes, you can await getBalanceApple with

```
await getBalanceApple.wait();

console.log(`balance: ${getBalanceApple}`);
```

Then print this object in the console to check if the call works.

Also make sure to check if "balanceArea" is the right elementID on your website otherwise ${data} will always be 0.

The error message

```
Balance: Not Connected to Contract
```

indicates that your frontend can't find your deployed contract. Check also that you're on the same network when testing, where you initially deployed it.